# Python3 Print Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This probably an easy question but I just can't seem to make it work consistently for different permutations.

What is the Python3 equivalent of this?

```
print >> sys.stdout, "Generated file: %s in directory %s\n" % (name+".wav", outdir)
```

I've tried

```
print("String to print %s %s\n", file=sys.stdout % (var1, var2))
```

and

```
print("String to print {} {}\n".format(var1, var2), file=sys.stdout)
```

What is the best way to do this in Python3 now that the >> operator is no more.  I know the % () has the be within the closing parenthesis of the print function but I always have trouble when using formatting as well as printing to a specific file/stream at the same time.

Comment: The second one, `print("String to print {} {}\n".format(var1, var2), file=sys.stdout)` works for me. Are you sure you have `sys` imported in your prompt?

Comment: To know the better way .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Comment: what is the first command supposed to achieve?

Comment: Yes I had sys imported.  Not sure what the problem was, probably a typo but I wanted to figure out using % with the new print anyway.  It's not supposed to achieve anything as it already prints to stdout, was just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the percent right next to the end of the string literal.

```
print("String to print %s %s\n" % (var1, var2), file=sys.stdout)
```

The percent operator is just like any other binary operator. It goes between the two things it's operating on -- in this case, the format string and the format arguments. It's the same reason that `print(2+2, file=sys.stdout)` works and `print(2, file=sys.stdout + 2)` doesn't.

---

(personal opinion corner: I think `format` is way better than percent style formatting, so you should just use your third code block, which behaves properly as you've written it)

Comment: is this not the same as `print("String to print {} {}\n".format(var1, var2), file=sys.stdout)`?

Comment: Yeah. I'm interpreting the question as, "the first and third code blocks in my question work, but not the second. How do I get percent formatting to behave the same way `format` does?"

Comment: I was mostly also trying to understand using the % in Python3  so I could convert some python 2 code more easily.  Yes I know 2to3 exists, but sometimes it's easier to just do it yourself in a few places.