# How to print correctly in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I tried to print content like following, it returned errors like `invalid syntax`

My runtime is `python3.8`

Where is the wrong point of this ?

`print 'Content: {}'.format(content)`

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Comment: In python 3x you need `()` around whatever you are printing, like this :`print('Content: {}'.format(content))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 Print Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347411/python3-print-function)

Answer (score 0):

This looks awfully like python 2 code. You need to provide parenthesis from python 3 onwards in print statements

```
print ('Content: {}'.format(content))
```

This will do too.

```
print(f'Content: {content}')
```